# How to get external data in famo.us app

Tags: javascript, rest, famo.us

I need to read/write data via Service (e.g. REST). That's easy as long as the famo.us app works within/as a website, as I would host it within the same domain server where the data is hosted on. What if I translate the app into an Android app? How am I supposed to read/write to the server?

JS per se is no allowed to do a simple http request to other sites so I guess it won't work when it's translated into an Android (or iOs) app either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work without a problem in Cordova as it allows cross site requests. Or you could use JSONP